# How to begin solving this cyrptarithm?

Tags: cryptarithm

Anybody please help me in how to begin with this cryptarithm. I tried to find for 0,1,5,6,9 but none of them are clearly recognizable..

o u i * o u i

---

```
   l i a r
 m l m a
```

t h u s

---

m s i e u r

Comment: o,u,i,l,a,r,m,t,h,s,e: 11 symbols... really???

Comment: I'd start by looking at $u$. It isn't often that the tens digit of $x$ and $x^2$ are the same.

Comment: Try 783*783 (1-st sieve: as Gerry Myerson said, 2-st sieve: oui*u = mlma, m on 1-st and 3-rd place, m>t>0). Here a=h=4.

Comment: Just a note: not all cryptarithms are in base 10.

Answer (score 2):

Starting hint:

First note that there are 11 symbols in cryptarithm: **o,u,i,l,a,r,m,t,h,s,e**.
So, in decimal system, at least two of symbols are equal.

**A).** 
**t** +1 = **m**. $\ \ \implies \ $ 
thus < mlma $\ \ \implies \ $ 
oui*o < oui*u $\ \ \implies \ $
**o** < **u**.

**B).**
oui*oui = msieur $\ \ \implies \ $ **m** $\le$ **o**, $\ \ $ **o** $\ge$ $3$.

**C).**
So we get:
$\ \ 0$ < **t** < **m** $\le$ **o** < **u** $\ \ \ \ $  ( **t** + 1 = **m** ).

**D).**
Applying comment of Gerry Myerson, we search "**ui**", such that **u** $\ge$ 4,

```
_ui * _ui = ____ur,
```

and get 6 possible cases:

```
_43 * _43 = ____49,
_63 * _63 = ____69,
_69 * _69 = ____61,
_74 * _74 = ____76,
_76 * _76 = ____76,  (here i=r=6),
_83 * _83 = ____89.
```

**E).**
Now we search "**oui**", where **o** $\ge$ $3$,  and

```
oui * u = mlma.
```

_43: no results;
_63: no results;
_69: no results;
_74: no results;
_76: 476 * 7 = 3332;
_83: 783 * 8 = 6264.

**F).**
There are 2 possible numbers for "**oui**": $476$ and $783$.

$783$ * $783$ works, but a=h=4 (because there are 11 symbols in cryptarithm: o,u,i,l,a,r,m,t,h,s,e).

Comment: OP only asked for help in beginning.

Comment: A long time spent. no reaction. I decided to continue answer.